Why is there still a Bad Trend of Migrating Mathematics Questions in Statistics to Cross Validated
There exists already substantial amount of posts discussing this serious issue in Meta, see for example Hasty migration of mathematical statistics questions to stats.SE .
I would like to address the issue one more time in this new post, along with some of the latest examples to show that is issue is not only unsolved, but gets more serious by the day in the sense that the migration seems to have become more blind. I would like to also ask the question in the interest of solving the issue that, for at least the author of the post, if there is any way at all to reject (or vote to reject) the migration (else than entirely copy paste the post). If the answer is no, why doesn't the site create such a mechanism?
Here are some hard evidence on inappropriate migrations :

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657594/show-model-is-identifiable-estimatable-for-mle-with-non-central-chi2-distr?noredirect=1#comment1235838_657594 The question is migrated pretty much immediately after it gets posted. It asks about whether a specific statistical model is identifiable and what are strategies to prove identifiability. The question is thus purely about the details of a mathematical proof.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/655817/examples-of-problems-in-statistics-accessible-only-using-information-geometry I first posted this purely mathematical question about statistics and geometry on Cross Validated. After receiving no answer, I posted it on Mathematics Stack Exchange. Despite explicitly claiming this history, it gets migrated as if no one actually looked at the post. (In the end, the question gets posted on Math Overflow and receive high upvotes).
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/656907/definition-of-regular-estimators The most important part of this question is a mathematical definition. Yet it gets migrated.

In general, search migrated:yes [mathematical-statistics] on Cross Validated and you will get a lot more such candidates.

A 13 year old post does not strike me as evidence of a "substantial amount of posts discussing this serious issue".

The single answer (at the time of this comment) suggests that "where is the question most likely to receive the best answer" as the migration criterion. Please describe your alternative, and why it's better. After all, lots of disciplines use mathematical definitions and proofs - that does not automatically make math.se the best place to find people who know about them.

The problem why people complains about migration is that there is NO alternative. People ask about mathematical statistics on Mathematics Stack Exchange/Math Overflow because they want and need mathematicians knowing statistics theory to answer their question. Cross Validated people most likely do NOT know about mathematical statistics and thus is NOT a valid place to ask these questions.

Cross Validated people most likely don't know about mathematical statistics, but the help center over at Cross Validated seems to have "mathematical statistics" in their "allowed list of topics" for asking questions. So maybe these questions above should be migrated, but they don't get answered properly there because there aren't enough experts at CV? That's what I read from "Cross Validated people most likely do NOT know about mathematical statistics and thus is NOT a valid place to ask these questions.".

If you actually go ask questions on Cross Validated you will know what I mean. They tend to not dive into details of mathematical proofs and that is totally fine as a statistics exchange site. However, when certain questions explicitly asking proof details gets migrated, things start to become annoying. The fact that Cross Validated has a "mathematical statistics" tag says it all. Just look at how many tags about mathematical statistics are there at Mathematics Stack Exchange : it is way more finely divided and specific.

A good point to discuss. However the point is NOT about how well the user base of CV is acquainted with "mathematical statistics". Surely the key is which site has more people with prowess in mathematical statistics as opposed to the level of sophistication of the average user. Compare with the following. A basic question in, say, class field theory, is off-topic in MathOverflow, but ok here. Yet, MO has more people familiar the area than we do here. Furthermore, the user base of MSE at large is totally ignorant about class field theory. Yet, MSE is the proper site to ask.

A similar situation may exist between MSE and Crypto.SE. Both sites allow questions about cryptography. It may or may not be better to ask a question about, say, algebra related to some crypto scheme here. There will be somewhat competent people on both sites, though the answers will be different.

Overall: The number-one thing you can do to avoid undesired migrations of your questions is to ensure your questions are useful to others, relevant, and contain helpful context.  In other words, the more valuable you can make your questions towards the mission of this site, the more likely that they'll be well-received here and not migrated away.
Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.  This is generally not considered appropriate on Stack Exchange.
If you're really asking why undesirable migrations sometimes happen: It's because migration, as a feature, hasn't worked out so well and is often misused.  In my opinion, it causes problems more often than it solves problems.  There is a lot of misunderstanding about when migration is and isn't supposed to be used.  My experience is that in most cases, rather than migrating questions, it would instead be better to close the question and let the poster delete the question and re-ask it elsewhere.  (See, e.g., A proposed philosophy of question migration)
Stats.SE can reject the migration by closing the question on Stats.SE.
Generally speaking, it's not uncommon for people to migrate for the wrong reasons.  For instance, some people migrate because they think the question is "better suited" on another site.  That's well-intentioned, but it is actually contrary to Stack Exchange rules.  We're not supposed to migrate questions that are on-topic on the original site (unless the original poster asks us to).  We're only supposed to migrate questions that are off-topic here, and that we believe will be well-received elsewhere.  Just because a question will get better answers elsewhere doesn't make it off-topic here.  "It is more likely to get a good answer elsewhere" is not an acceptable reason to close a question, and does not make the question off-topic here.  (See, e.g., What is migration and how does it work?)
Also, sometimes people migrate low-quality questions, out of a desire to be helpful.  They know it is not suitable here, and they want to help the poster, so they try to think of some place where it might be suitable, and migrate it there.  That sometimes is appropriate, but not always.  In particular, if the question is low quality or doesn't meet the norms and expectations of the other site, then it's not appropriate to migrate it there.  (See, e.g., Add a "don't migrate crap" migration 'path' to all sites, To migrate or not to migrate?)

Huhn, I had no idea that was the official standard. Thanks for the info.

If it helps, you can think of migration - the way it's supposed to be used - as the community saying "we're closing this question because it's off topic here, but we think it's likely to be on topic somewhere else so we're doing you a favor by posting it there on your behalf." (Back when I was more active on SE, I had suggested changing the way migration votes work so that you would have to choose to close the question as off topic first, and then you get a chance to pick another site to migrate it to. But that idea never got much traction.)

My criteria for migration is as follows. If the question is more likely to be answered on Cross-Validated (CV) than it is to be answered on MSE, then I vote to migrate to CV.
On MSE, only a fraction of the user base is interested in statistics, while the entire user base of CV is interested in statistics. It is totally fine to leave low-level statistics questions on MSE, but for a very advanced statistics question, the audience of potential answerers at MSE is so small that the question might go unnoticed if it is left on MSE.
Here are my thoughts on why it is OK to migrate last two of the three questions you mentioned. For the first question, I will just share my thoughts.

The question here describes a statistical model, then asks, "Is this model identifiable?". I don't even know the definition of a  statistical model being identifiable, and I have taken graduate level statistics courses. Clearly, this is an advanced statistics question, best answered by the pros at CV. Responding to the first comment on this answer, I see now that identifiable is defined in the post, so this is appropriate on MSE. I have no strong feelings on whether migration is appropriate here.

Well, for your second question, it would have been OK to leave it on MSE, because the fact it was answered on MathOverflow means it qualifies as a math question. Still, the idea of information geometry is alien to me. If this were to be left on MSE, then it would be missing context, so it either needed to be closed for lacking context or migrated to a place where that context is OK to leave out.

Again, the way this question is asked assumes a deep understanding of statistics that most users on MSE do not have, so it would need a lot more context to be acceptable on MSE. The asker mentions Hodge's estimator, without further explanation; most MSE users do not know what Hodge's estimator is, so this question would be missing context on MSE. Also, this question defines super-efficient estimators as "they are unnatural and have undesirable local properties associated with them". I think this definition with imprecise language only suffices as a definition to experts; the audience at MSE tends to demand that concepts like this be explicitly spelled out.



I disagree with your answer. Statisticians in Cross Validated typically do NOT know mathematical statistics. Once it comes to mathematical details, Mathematical Stack Exchange is a way better place. How do you except someone to answer a math question on a site with the only tag on statistics being "mathematical statistics". Moreover, your reasons to reject my evidence are not valid. Identifiability is defined in post and is the first definition in decision theory. If you haven't heard about identifiability/information geometry, treat it as an unfamiliar field of math to you.

If the question is on-topic on Math.SE, then it is inappropriate to migrate the question (unless the original poster requests it).  Migration is only supposed to be used for questions that are off-topic here.  (See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/160917.)   If the question lacks sufficient context, it should be closed as 'unclear', rather than migrated.

I'm utterly bewildered by your statements in paragraph 3. If I post a question that mentions étale cohomology, should I define what is meant by cohomology of a sheaf of a site? Should I define a site? Grothendieck topology? Coverage? Cochain complex? Category? How far should I go so that "audience at MSE" will be satisfied? Back to the axioms of ZFC? Why those non-experts are treated as primary audience, despite them being ABSOLUTELY UNABLE to understand the question REGARDLESS of whether all words in the question are defined, or not?
